# Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL (getting this error trying to deploy my portfolio site to Netlify)

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, netlify

Trying to deploy my React portfolio site to Netlify. Installed Netlify with `npm i netlify-cli`.

Then, ran `npx netlify init` to get logged into Netlify and answer some of the setup questions within the terminal.

Next, the terminal question is now: "Netlify CLI needs access to your GitHub account to configure Webhooks and Deploy Keys. What would you like to do?"

When I select "Authorize with GitHub through app.netlify.com", I'm taken to a "Sign in to Netlify CLI" page on Netlify's website and the following error is on the page so I cannot move forward with the process:

```
Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4xao.png) is a picture of the error, for clarity.

Another piece of info is that earlier on I ran a build command which built me what I believe is a production build. The stuff from that is located in a build folder in my project directory.

Anyone know why I'm getting this error or a good way to get around it?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same problem. Have you ever found a solution?